# lodash array methods work but not string or math methods

Tags: lodash, plunker

I have played lodash in plunker and found a strange issue: the array methods works but not string or math methods. 
These work:

```
_.first([1, 2, 3]);
_.isObject(v);
```

But these do not work:

```
 _.min([4, 2, 8, 6]);
 _.endsWith('abc', 'c');
```

Please help me figure it out. Here is the [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/87ns3VdINyJP42ZIprd9?p=preview). It is forked from a lodash [demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/hRe4awZjnrHW0pTPJrD5/preview).

Comment: It turns out i used the old version 2.4.1 of lodash. it works if used current 3.9.3 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an old version of lodash.  Your `_.min` call is working fine (try just running `var v = _.min([4, 2, 8, 6]);`).  `_.endsWith` isn't working because it doesn't exist in the version of lodash that you're using.